# Bar chart with dates on X and two values on each each date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I want to create a bar chart in Google Sheets which looks (pretty much) like this :

[image: bar chart]

From data that looks like this :

[image: data]

As you can see in the first picture the date labels along the X axis skip a date so that every second pair of values is left with a label. I want every pair of red/blue values to share a value from the '1' row shown in the sheet.

EDIT1:
The Data range is : C1:J1,B5:AA5,B25:J25 .

The following screen dump gives you a fuller view of all the settings

[image]

Comment: @pnuts : thank you for your comment. I'm just about to edit the question to include the information about the Data range.

Answer (score 1):

Google Sheets will do this when the axis units are recognized as a date. Double click on the horizontal axis, and check the `Treat Labels As Text` setting.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]